# Where does Stack Overflow store GitHub profile links?

Tags: stackexchange, dataexplorer

I was going through Stack Overflow db structure on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries and wondering where the user's GitHub link is.

I can see the website URL listed against user in schema but there is no field referencing GitHub profile link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **cross-site duplicate** of [*Why are links to social media and GitHub not appearing in the SE data dump?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306015/why-are-links-to-social-media-and-github-not-appearing-in-the-se-data-dump) (And SEDE).

There [a Stack Exchange developer says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307696/148310):

> Those don't appear in the data dump or in SEDE because the social media/GitHub links aren't stored in the `Users` table - it only has the `WebsiteUrl` column.
>
> The others links are stored in a separate `UsersMetadata` table that isn't included in any of the public data dumps.

You can also see that [the additional links are **not in the Stack Exchange API**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user).

---

There does not seem to be a compelling reason why these public links are unavailable other than Stack Exchange has so far, de facto, decided that it was not a cost-effective use of dev time.

You can *try* creating a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange...

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't store GitHub profile links.

Most queries written to "Select GitHub users with..." uses the `WebsiteUrl` parameter and a `LIKE` statement.

The top few queries on data.stackexchange.com for example has the following query:

```
SELECT 
  u.Id, 
  u.WebsiteUrl, 
  u.UpVotes, 
  u.Reputation
FROM Users u
WHERE WebsiteUrl LIKE '%github.com%' AND u.Reputation > 1
```

This of course is the `WebsiteUrl` variable from its schema:
[image: github schema]

Comment: I doubt that because I just added my GitHub profile link on my stack-overflow profile and I can't see that in query results against my profile at least not in column WebsiteUrl ?

Comment: @WaqarUlKhaf data.stackoverflow.com is not real-time. If you’ve been active lately you’ll notice that the reputation (score) is not even updated. What I described is the actual schema.

Comment: sounds true but how are they asking for 3 preferences then i-e website link , twitter link and github link ?